# Albeit + -ing clause

Tags: conjunctions, ing

Is it possible to use an -ing clause after "albeit"? Example:

> We should praise the market's efficiency, albeit recognising the need for regulation.

Comment: There may be a mix-up here. You could have recognising after albeit, but not in this sentence with the subject *We*. Albeit has the word *it* inside, and becomes the subject of that clause. So, *albeit needing* regulation (= even though *it* might need regulation). Or, *while* (we should be) recognising the need for regulation.

Comment: Yes, although _although_ is more common; _albeit_ is probly too high-register for economic discussion.

Comment: No: "albeit", as used in an adjunct of concession, takes only a verbless clause as complement.

Comment: If you swap in *although*, you can see that this doesn't work: *We should praise the market's efficiency, although recognising the need for regulation.* Try *while* instead: *We should praise the market's efficiency while recognising the need for regulation.* Or *even while* to keep the contrast: *We should praise the market's efficiency, even while recognising the need for regulation.*